# How can I permutate items in a line with two different separators?

Tags: bash, permutation

My dataset (`dataset.csv`) is structured like this:

```
NFDI4Culture, NFDI4Memory, NFDI4Objects, Text+;Alliance
BERD@NFDI, Text+;Event: conference organisation
NFDI4Cat, NFDI4Chem, FAIRmat, DAPHNE4NFDI;Event: conference participation
PUNCH4NFDI, FAIRmat, DAPHNE4NFDI;Event: conference participation
```

Each line consists of at least two values separated by a `,` and at the end of line (separated by `;`) there is the categorization of the items before.

The desired result should look like (columns are *tab*-separated):

```
NFDI4Culture  NFDI4Memory  Alliance
NFDI4Culture  NFDI4Objects  Alliance
NFDI4Culture  Text+  Alliance
NFDI4Memory  NFDI4Objects  Alliance
NFDI4Memory  Text+  Alliance
NFDI4Objects  Text+  Alliance
BERD@NFDI  Text+  Event: conference organisation
NFDI4Cat  NFDI4Chem  Event: conference organisation
NFDI4Cat  FAIRmat  Event: conference organisation
NFDI4Cat  DAPHNE4NFDI  Event: conference organisation
NFDI4Chem  FAIRmat  Event: conference organisation
NFDI4Chem  DAPHNE4NFDI  Event: conference organisation
FAIRmat  DAPHNE4NFDI  Event: conference organisation
PUNCH4NFDI  FAIRmat  Event: conference organisation
PUNCHE4NFDI  DAPHNE4NFDI  Event: conference organisation
FAIRmat  DAPHNE4NFDI  Event: conference organisation
```

A permutation of each item which is separated by a `,` in the dataset, is needed and additionally at the end there should be printed the categorization.

With recylcing some old code I ge almose the needed output:

```bash
while IFS=\,  read -r -a names; do
        for ((i = 0; i < ${#names[@]} - 1; ++i)); do
            for ((j = i + 1; j < ${#names[@]}; ++j)); do
                echo -e "${names[i]}\t${names[j]}"
            done
        done
done < $dataset
```

The result is this:

```
NFDI4Culture    NFDI4Memory
NFDI4Culture    NFDI4Objects
NFDI4Culture    Text+;Alliance
NFDI4Memory NFDI4Objects
NFDI4Memory Text+;Alliance
NFDI4Objects    Text+;Alliance
BERD@NFDI   Text+;Event:conferenceorganisation
NFDI4Cat    NFDI4Chem
NFDI4Cat    FAIRmat
NFDI4Cat    DAPHNE4NFDI;Event:conferenceparticipation
NFDI4Chem   FAIRmat
NFDI4Chem   DAPHNE4NFDI;Event:conferenceparticipation
FAIRmat DAPHNE4NFDI;Event:conferenceparticipation
PUNCH4NFDI  FAIRmat
PUNCH4NFDI  DAPHNE4NFDI;Event:conferenceparticipation
FAIRmat DAPHNE4NFDI;Event:conferenceparticipation
```

The problem is the categorization which is obviously no printed for each line.

Comment: several rows in the expected output appear to be missing `conference participation` ... typo?

Comment: If it is **guaranteed** that every line has the last field denoted by semicolon, you could use `awk -F '[,;]` to process the file. For each linput line, you then loop from the second to the but-last field and print one output line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General approach:

- split each line on `;` and save as variables `vals` and `category`
- split `vals` on `,` and save in `arr[]` array
- remove leading/trailing spaces from `arr[]` entries
- use 2 `for` loops to generate permutations

One `bash` idea:

```
while IFS=';' read -r vals category                         # split on ";"
do
    IFS=, read -ra arr <<< "${vals}"                        # split on ","
    count="${#arr[@]}"

    shopt -s extglob
    for ((i=0; i<count; i++))
    do
        arr[$i]="${arr[$i]##*( )}"                          # remove leading spaces
        arr[$i]="${arr[$i]%%*( )}"                          # remove trailing spaces
    done
    shopt -u extglob

    for ((i=0; i<(count-1); i++))
    do
        for ((j=i+1; j<count; j++))
        do
            printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" "${arr[i]}" "${arr[j]}" "${category}"
        done
    done
done < dataset.csv
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=";"; OFS="\t" }                                  # split input on ";"
      { n=split($1,arr,",")                                 # $1 == "vals"; further split first field on "," and store results in array arr[]
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {                              # loop through arr[] entries and ...
            gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",arr[i])   # remove leading/trailing spaces
        }
        for (i=1; i<n; i++)                                 # generate permultations ...
            for (j=i+1; j<=n; j++)
                print arr[i],arr[j], $2                     # $2 == "category"
      }
' dataset.csv
```

These both generate:

```
NFDI4Culture    NFDI4Memory     Alliance
NFDI4Culture    NFDI4Objects    Alliance
NFDI4Culture    Text+   Alliance
NFDI4Memory     NFDI4Objects    Alliance
NFDI4Memory     Text+   Alliance
NFDI4Objects    Text+   Alliance
BERD@NFDI       Text+   Event: conference organisation
NFDI4Cat        NFDI4Chem       Event: conference participation
NFDI4Cat        FAIRmat Event: conference participation
NFDI4Cat        DAPHNE4NFDI     Event: conference participation
NFDI4Chem       FAIRmat Event: conference participation
NFDI4Chem       DAPHNE4NFDI     Event: conference participation
FAIRmat DAPHNE4NFDI     Event: conference participation
PUNCH4NFDI      FAIRmat Event: conference participation
PUNCH4NFDI      DAPHNE4NFDI     Event: conference participation
FAIRmat DAPHNE4NFDI     Event: conference participation
```

---

Tweaking OP's current code to use a dual field delimiter:

```
while IFS='[,;]' read -r -a names
do
    count="${#names[@]}"

    for ((i = 0; i < count-2; i++))
    do
        for ((j = i+1; j <= count-2; j++))
        do
            echo -e "${names[i]}\t${names[j]}\t${names[count-1]}"
        done
    done
done < dataset.csv
```

**NOTE:** this does not remove leading/trailing spaces from fields; OP can copy the code for removing leading/trailing spaces from previous (above) `bash` solution

This generates:

```
NFDI4Culture     NFDI4Memory    Alliance
NFDI4Culture     NFDI4Objects   Alliance
NFDI4Culture     Text+  Alliance
 NFDI4Memory     NFDI4Objects   Alliance
 NFDI4Memory     Text+  Alliance
 NFDI4Objects    Text+  Alliance
BERD@NFDI        Text+  Event: conference organisation
NFDI4Cat         NFDI4Chem      Event: conference participation
NFDI4Cat         FAIRmat        Event: conference participation
NFDI4Cat         DAPHNE4NFDI    Event: conference participation
 NFDI4Chem       FAIRmat        Event: conference participation
 NFDI4Chem       DAPHNE4NFDI    Event: conference participation
 FAIRmat         DAPHNE4NFDI    Event: conference participation
PUNCH4NFDI       FAIRmat        Event: conference participation
PUNCH4NFDI       DAPHNE4NFDI    Event: conference participation
 FAIRmat         DAPHNE4NFDI    Event: conference participation
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution in [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr) Lisp:

```
(while-match `@itemcsv;@category` (get-line)
  (let ((items (tok #/[^, ]+/ itemcsv)))
    (each-match ((@a @b) (comb items 2))
      (put-line `@a\t@b\t@category`))))
```

Terminology note: the `comb` function is used because we are in fact after *combinations* and not *permutations*. Order is significant in permutations. The set {A, B, C} yields six two-element permutations, but only three two-element combinations (what we want).

Run:

```
$ txr perm.tl < data
NFDI4Culture    NFDI4Memory     Alliance
NFDI4Culture    NFDI4Objects    Alliance
NFDI4Culture    Text+   Alliance
NFDI4Memory     NFDI4Objects    Alliance
NFDI4Memory     Text+   Alliance
NFDI4Objects    Text+   Alliance
BERD@NFDI       Text+   Event: conference organisation
NFDI4Cat        NFDI4Chem       Event: conference participation
NFDI4Cat        FAIRmat Event: conference participation
NFDI4Cat        DAPHNE4NFDI     Event: conference participation
NFDI4Chem       FAIRmat Event: conference participation
NFDI4Chem       DAPHNE4NFDI     Event: conference participation
FAIRmat DAPHNE4NFDI     Event: conference participation
PUNCH4NFDI      FAIRmat Event: conference participation
PUNCH4NFDI      DAPHNE4NFDI     Event: conference participation
FAIRmat DAPHNE4NFDI     Event: conference participation
```

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes that your fields do not contain field separators (commas and semi-colons). With any POSIX awk:

```
awk -F ',[[:space:]]*|;' -v OFS='\t' '
  {for(i=1;i<=NF-2;i++) for(j=i+1;j<=NF-1;j++) print $i,$j,$NF}' "$dataset"
```

We define the input field separator (`-F` option) as a comma followed by any number of spaces (`,[[:space:]]*`) or (`|`) a semi-colon (`;`), and we define the output field separator (variable `OFS`) as a tab (`\t`). Then, for each input line, we print your expected output with 2 nested loops.

If you really prefer `bash`, with almost the same ideas as with `awk`:

```
while IFS=',;' read -ra a; do
  n=${#a[@]}
  for((i=0;i<n-2;i++)); do
    for((j=i+1;j<n-1;j++)); do
      printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' "${a[i]# }" "${a[j]# }" "${a[n-1]}"
    done
  done
done < "$dataset"
```

Note the `${a[i]# }` and `${a[j]# }` to remove the leading white space (the ones after the commas in the input).

Answer (score 1):

If [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) is available, arrays come with a [`.permutation`](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Array:permutation) method.

It also has [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)+[sed](/questions/tagged/sed) emulation switches for a tidy approach:

```bash
ruby -F';' -a -n -e 'items, category = $F
items.split(", ").permutation(2).each {|perm|
   puts perm.push(category).join "\t"
}
' file.csv
```

- `-a` (autosplit, store result in `$F`)
- `-F` (field sep regex)
- `-n` (read eval loop, no default print)

Output:

```
NFDI4Culture    NFDI4Memory Alliance
NFDI4Culture    NFDI4Objects    Alliance
NFDI4Culture    Text+   Alliance
NFDI4Memory NFDI4Culture    Alliance
NFDI4Memory NFDI4Objects    Alliance
NFDI4Memory Text+   Alliance
NFDI4Objects    NFDI4Culture    Alliance
NFDI4Objects    NFDI4Memory Alliance
NFDI4Objects    Text+   Alliance
Text+   NFDI4Culture    Alliance
Text+   NFDI4Memory Alliance
Text+   NFDI4Objects    Alliance
BERD@NFDI   Text+   Event: conference organisation
Text+   BERD@NFDI   Event: conference organisation
NFDI4Cat    NFDI4Chem   Event: conference participation
NFDI4Cat    FAIRmat Event: conference participation
NFDI4Cat    DAPHNE4NFDI Event: conference participation
NFDI4Chem   NFDI4Cat    Event: conference participation
NFDI4Chem   FAIRmat Event: conference participation
NFDI4Chem   DAPHNE4NFDI Event: conference participation
FAIRmat NFDI4Cat    Event: conference participation
FAIRmat NFDI4Chem   Event: conference participation
FAIRmat DAPHNE4NFDI Event: conference participation
DAPHNE4NFDI NFDI4Cat    Event: conference participation
DAPHNE4NFDI NFDI4Chem   Event: conference participation
DAPHNE4NFDI FAIRmat Event: conference participation
PUNCH4NFDI  FAIRmat Event: conference participation
PUNCH4NFDI  DAPHNE4NFDI Event: conference participation
FAIRmat PUNCH4NFDI  Event: conference participation
FAIRmat DAPHNE4NFDI Event: conference participation
DAPHNE4NFDI PUNCH4NFDI  Event: conference participation
DAPHNE4NFDI FAIRmat Event: conference participation
```

You could also use the [CSV module](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/csv/CSV) instead of `.split` depending on the complexity of the "CSV" input.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a recursive function to achieve this.

#### shell script without comments

```
#!/bin/bash

function pick_2_recursively {
    first_arg=$1
    shift
    rest_args=("${@}")
    [[ ${#rest_args[@]} -eq 1 ]] && echo -e "${first_arg}\t${rest_args[*]}\t${category}" && exit
    for arg in "${rest_args[@]}"
    do
        echo -e "${first_arg}\t${arg}\t${category}"
    done
    pick_2_recursively "${rest_args[@]}"
}


while read -r line ; do
    category=$(echo "${line}" | grep -Po ';\K.+') 
    export category
    values=("$(echo "${line}" | grep -Po '(.+)(,.+)(?=;)' | tr ',' ' ')")
    echo "${values[*]}" | xargs -I {} bash -c "$(declare -f pick_2_recursively) ; pick_2_recursively {} "
done < <(cat dataset.csv)
```

#### output

```
NFDI4Culture    NFDI4Memory Alliance
NFDI4Culture    NFDI4Objects    Alliance
NFDI4Culture    Text+   Alliance
NFDI4Memory NFDI4Objects    Alliance
NFDI4Memory Text+   Alliance
NFDI4Objects    Text+   Alliance
BERD@NFDI   Text+   Event: conference organisation
NFDI4Cat    NFDI4Chem   Event: conference participation
NFDI4Cat    FAIRmat Event: conference participation
NFDI4Cat    DAPHNE4NFDI Event: conference participation
NFDI4Chem   FAIRmat Event: conference participation
NFDI4Chem   DAPHNE4NFDI Event: conference participation
FAIRmat DAPHNE4NFDI Event: conference participation
PUNCH4NFDI  FAIRmat Event: conference participation
PUNCH4NFDI  DAPHNE4NFDI Event: conference participation
FAIRmat DAPHNE4NFDI Event: conference participation
```

#### shell script with comments

```
#!/bin/bash

# the recursive function
function pick_2_recursively {
    first_arg=$1
    shift
    rest_args=("${@}")

    # terminate condition: when the 'rest' param left only 1.
    [[ ${#rest_args[@]} -eq 1 ]] && echo -e "${first_arg}\t${rest_args[*]}\t${category}" && exit

    # main recursive loop: print out first and each param respectively.
    for arg in "${rest_args[@]}"
    do
        echo -e "${first_arg}\t${arg}\t${category}"
    done

    # since the first param is already 'shifted', the original second param now be the first param for this call.
    pick_2_recursively "${rest_args[@]}"
}


while read -r line ; do
    # assign 'category' to all strings after the ';'
    category=$(echo "${line}" | grep -Po ';\K.+')
    
    # make 'category' global.
    export category

    # assign 'value' to all string separated with comma before the ';'
    values=("$(echo "${line}" | grep -Po '(.+)(,.+)(?=;)' | tr ',' ' ')") 

    # pass each line into the recursive function. 
    echo "${values[*]}" | xargs -I {} bash -c "$(declare -f pick_2_recursively) ; pick_2_recursively {} "
done < <(cat dataset.csv)
```

#### explanation

1. Treat original data into 3 group:

```
# e.g.

NFDI4Culture, NFDI4Memory, NFDI4Objects, Text+;Alliance
^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^
first param   rest params                      category
```

2. our goal is to list

```
first_param   <tab>   {each param from rest params}   <tab>   {category}
```

3. to get 'category' variable, use `grep`

```
category=$(echo "${line}" | grep -Po ';\K.+')

# means match all non-empty right after the ';'
```

4. to pass params into the recursive function, need to extract 'values' with `grep` again

```
values=("$(echo "${line}" | grep -Po '(.+)(,.+)(?=;)' | tr ',' ' ')") 

# means match all separated with comma right before ';'
# then replace all ',' into ' ' 
# and we get 'params' that can be passed into the recursive function
```

5. in side the recursive function, echo the desired output for each line.

For example:

sample line in original input

```
NFDI4Cat, NFDI4Chem, FAIRmat, DAPHNE4NFDI;Event: conference participation
```

now became this

- `category` : `Event: conference participation`
- `values` : `NFDI4Cat NFDI4Chem FAIRmat DAPHNE4NFDI`

and each recursive call split `values` into 2 groups:

1. first param : `NFDI4Cat`
2. rest param : `NFDI4Chem FAIRmat DAPHNE4NFDI`

each loop prints

```
{first param}\t{rest param [0]}\t{category}
{first param}\t{rest param [1]}\t{category}
{first param}t{rest param [2]}\t{category}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F' *,|;' '
   {
     while(NF>2){
         for(i=NF-1;i>1;i--)
            printf "%s \t  %s \t %s\n", $1,$i,$NF 
         NF-=1
   }
}
' <(rev file)|rev

NFDI4Culture     NFDI4Memory     Alliance
NFDI4Culture     NFDI4Objects    Alliance
NFDI4Culture     Text+           Alliance
NFDI4Memory      NFDI4Objects    Alliance
NFDI4Memory      Text+           Alliance
NFDI4Objects     Text+           Alliance
BERD@NFDI        Text+           Event: conference organisation
NFDI4Cat         NFDI4Chem       Event: conference participation
NFDI4Cat         FAIRmat         Event: conference participation
NFDI4Cat         DAPHNE4NFDI     Event: conference participation
NFDI4Chem        FAIRmat         Event: conference participation
NFDI4Chem        DAPHNE4NFDI     Event: conference participation
FAIRmat          DAPHNE4NFDI     Event: conference participation
PUNCH4NFDI       FAIRmat         Event: conference participation
PUNCH4NFDI       DAPHNE4NFDI     Event: conference participation
FAIRmat          DAPHNE4NFDI     Event: conference participation
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a brand new solution per se but simply building off of **@ufopilot**'s existing framework :

```
 Tue     | $5  := "EDT"
         |              2023
 Tue     | $4  := "20:21:47"
         |              2023
 Tue     | $3  := "26"
         |              2023
 Tue     | $2  := "Sep"
         |              2023

 Tue     | $4  := "20:21:47"
         |              EDT
 Tue     | $3  := "26"
         |              EDT
 Tue     | $2  := "Sep"
         |              EDT

 Tue     | $3  := "26"
         |              20:21:47
 Tue     | $2  := "Sep"
         |              20:21:47

 Tue     | $2  := "Sep"
         |              26
```

---

```
 mawk 'BEGIN { _______ = "\t%*s" (_ = "\15\t\t | ") "$%-*d := \"%s" \
                         "\"\14" (_)                 "\t\t\t%s%.*s"
                   ___ =  (__  =  _ = length(______ = "\n\n")) + _
 } __ < (_ = NF) {
    ____ = $+(_____ = $_)^!_
    do
        while (__ < _--)
            printf(_______, ___, ____, __, _, $_, _____,
                                  __ - (__ < _), ______)
    while (__ + (_____ = $(_ = --NF))^!+_ <= _)
 }'
```

---

Comment: I dont understand your proposed solution.

Comment: @lukascbossert : it's the same approach as `@ufopilot`'s solution above - printing from right-most field (i.e. column) inwards as long as 3 or more columns still exist in total. This way it avoids duplicative entries from permutations over the same combinations (i.e. once "A-B" is printed, then "B-A" would gets skipped)

Comment: Ok - it rather looks like art than code. A fancy way naming a variable `_` :)

Comment: @lukascbossert : using a 1-bit alphabet of just `_` has major advantages - because  there aren't any letters to create combinations of it, not only every variable must be uniquely named, they also must possess a unique width on the screen (best with fixed with fonts), so code that involves massive loop unrolling becomes ultra easy to debug….

Comment: @lukascbossert : …. the mere mis-typing of a variable would alter its screen width, thus ruining elegantly aligned columns by the slant induced, becomes a major eyesore visually, and spotting typos a lot sooner, with zero chance of unicode look-alikes to seep it, nefariously or otherwise.

Comment: @lukascbossert :   `_` isn't all that unique - shells have it `$_` , `perl` has it `$_ or @_`, `python` has it `_`, but designed in a way you cannot reliably expect it to retain  state information you assigned it if other actions with side effects have been performed since then.  The rules for `awk` var names, however, are very simple - any non-zero-length combo of `alphanumeric` (`[0-9A-Za-z]`) or `underscore` (`_`) chars within `ASCII` space, not starting with a number, and not identical to a reserved keyword. No where it ever says underscores must be paired with anything else.

Comment: @lukascbossert : …. which means `_` is absolutely nothing special at all in `awk`, and neither is `__` or `___`, & u're free to use them, with full expectations no side effects would alter its value other than what've you explicitly requested. Heck, it's even fully `POSIX-compliant` syntax to write  ::::::::::::: ::::::::  `function __(_) { return _*_ }` :::::::: it's helpful to your mind to get rid of the `alnum`s in varnames & just look at it syntactically and see something multiplied by that same thing, thus concluding it performs squaring, despite everything in underscores.

Comment: @lukascbossert : compare that to `function squaring(x) { return x*x }` ::::::::::::: :::::::::::::: you really don't care how the argument is named, so why reduce readability of it by calling it `x` ?